# Immutable list in C++

Tags: c++, immutability, immutablelist

How to make an immutable list in cpp?
The list's **reference** should be constant as well as **it's data**.

I don't to make a wrapper class over vector or any other container (I know that method similar to this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/java-immutable-objects)).

What is the best way to do this using `constexpr` or `const pointers`.

Comment: Not modifying the list is not a solution. The list should itself have a property that it cannot be modified once initialized.

Comment: Something like `const std::list<const T>` where `T` is your element type satisfies these properties already.

Comment: No. You can still add elements in it.

Comment: Once elements are added in it, No elements can be added or deleted nor any element can modified.

Comment: No you can't add elements to a `const std::list<T>`

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal None of the modifiers of `std::list` is `const` qualified, so there is no legal way of modification.

Comment: But T itself can be manipulated ? right ?

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal `const std::list<T>` does not provide any method to return a non-const reference to the elements. However, technically you might be allowed to `const_cast` the references returned in order to modify the elements (I am not sure if that is forbidden anywhere in the standard). Using `const T` would make this illegal (but undefined behavior, not compile-time error). But using `const_cast` this way shouldn't be done anyway, so `const std::list<T>` is sufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just declare it as `const`, like this:

```
const std::list<int> constList = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Methods like `constList.begin();` will return a `const_iterator` and calls like `constList.push_back(3);` will not compile.

Assigning its address to a non-const pointer won't work:

```
std::list<int> *l = &constList; // does not compile
```

Passing a reference to a function that takes a non-const reference doesn't work:

```
void a(std::list<int> &list) {}
int main()
{
    const std::list<int> mylist = { 1, 2, 3 };
    a(mylist); // does not compile
}
```

> Not modifying the list is not a solution.

Make a non-const list, and once you're done building it, move it to a `const` list:

```
std::list<int> mylist = { 1, 2, 3 };
mylist.push_back(4);
const std::list<int> constList = std::move(mylist);
```

Comment: Will the immutability of list remain on passing by reference as well as via pointer ?

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal that's right. You can only use it with `const` references and pointers to `const` list. I added an example to my post.

Comment: If the template instead of being a primitive data type was an object ? Then each object can be modified. right ? Then we will need immutability in T by itself to make list immutable.

Comment: @RishabhAgarwal No. Since the list is `const`, you get `const` iterators from it, and from those you get `const` references to `T`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use it as a `const std::list<T>`.
Both pointers in the following code will print out the same value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using T = double;

void some_function(const std::list<T>& list) {
    const double * ptr = &(*list.begin());
    std::cout << ptr << "\n";
    //list.push_back(3.0);//error list is const
}

int main() {
    std::list<T> list{3.4,-42};
    const std::list<T>& const_list = list;
    const double * ptr = &(*const_list.begin());
    std::cout << ptr << "\n";
    //const_list.push_back(3.0);//error list is const
    some_function(list);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no exist immutable list ..if you want to make any list immutable then go for it -> "Create a wrapper named class  whatever and create object of stl list  inside wrapper class and dont provide any function inside the whatever class and play game with whatever's object..."
now your list is immutable.